# Display error message inside dialog after unsuccessful form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a login form which pops out inside dialog after user clicks on link. Inside that form I have two username/password fields. If user successfully logs in, it redirects him to his profile page. The problem is if user doesn't sign in correctly. I want to display him some message inside same dialog and not close that dialog.

This is my dialog:

```
<div id="login" >
    <div>
        <%= form_for(:session, url: sessions_path) do |f| %>

        <%= f.label :username %>
        <%= f.text_field :username %>

        <%= f.label :password %>
        <%= f.password_field :password %>

        <%= f.submit "Sign in", class: "btn" %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my sessions controller:

```
def create
    user = User.find_by(username: params[:session][:username])
        if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
            sign_in user
            redirect_back_or(user)
        else
            flash.now[:error] = 'Error!'
            render 'new'
        end
end
```

So, you can see that currently after unsuccessful login, user is redirected to a new form on sign-in page where he can try to sign in again. My rendered error message is normally displayed there:

```
<%= render 'errors/login', object: f.object %>
```

If I put that message inside dialog, the following error is displayed immediately after I open site:

```
undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass
```

Probably because session is still "invisible". If I remove `render 'new'` for unsuccessful login from SessionsController, I receive the following error:

```
Missing template sessions/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "/Users/username/Applications/AppName/app/views"
```

So, I only want to keep pop-up dialog window if the user enters wrong username/password and display short message above form. What would be the best way to accomplish that? Thanks :)

Comment: there has to be a directory `error` and a file `login` where the error handling form is located.

Answer (score 0):

You've got 2 (3?) issues:

---

**nil:NilClass**

> undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass

I would surmise this error is caused by your passing / calling the form object incorrectly

You're currently passing `object: f.object`, I would do this:

```
<%= render 'errors/login', object: f, as: "form" %>
```

This will pass the form builder object and call it "form" in the partial. You'd then be able to call the form object like this:

```
#app/views/errors/login.html.erb
<%= form.errors.each do |error| %>
   //errors
<% end %>
```

---

**Template**

> Missing template sessions/create, application/create with
>   {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw,
>   :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in: *
>   "/Users/username/Applications/AppName/app/views"

This means you're calling a file which doesn't exist

Specifically, you'll need to have a file here:

```
#app/views/errors/login.html.erb
<%= your_code_here %>
```

---

**Unsuccessful**

Causing a dialogue to appear is more of a JS issue than an HTML / Rails one

I would certainly look at rendering a `.js.erb`, as this will allow you to dynamically load the dialogue element on the page

Comment: i have a similar question (same controller code). he never responded to this question, but i was wondering if you would please take a look at mine -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39357913/how-to-handle-errors-for-session-if-session-is-not-an-active-record-model