# How to handle errors for :session if Session is not an Active Record model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There is no Session model. How can I go about creating specific errors about why the form submission was unsuccessful beyond flashing a general failure notice?

> Recall from Section 7.3.3 that we displayed signup errors using the User model error messages. These errors are associated with a particular Active Record object, but this strategy won’t work here because the session isn’t an Active Record model. Instead, we’ll put a message in the flash to be displayed upon failed login.
>   [Rails Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/basic_login)

**Controller**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

   def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      if user.activated?
        log_in user
        params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(user) : forget(user)
        redirect_back_or user
      else
        message  = "Account not activated. "
        message += "Check your email for the activation link."
        flash[:warning] = message
        redirect_to root_url
      end
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

**Form**

```
<%= form_for(:session, url: login_path) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>
  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>
  <%= f.submit "Sign in", class: "btn btn-primary sessions" %>
<% end %>
```

Parameters are passed as:

> Started POST "/login" for 68.204.49.62 at 2016-09-06 17:33:59 +0000
>   2016-09-06T17:33:59.165393+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"DhKuJCjbeVgBOsQiujgd34540Vk3i5ouRFpAm8JnU9ZKWlMZhxN7VPnWJrfuuKmgFNTvsDfJNTXNLRpI1pHNebA==", "session"=>{"email"=>"simondang@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}

**Edit: So I thought of doing this?**

```
def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user 
      if user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
        if user.activated?
          log_in user
          params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(user) : forget(user)
          flash.now[:success] = "Great job dude!"
          redirect_back_or user
        elsif !user.activated?
          message  = "Account not activated. "
          message += "Check your email for the activation link."
          flash[:warning] = message
          redirect_to root_url
        else
         flash.now[:danger] = "Something went wrong, please try again."
         render 'new'  
        end
      elsif !user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
        flash.now[:danger] = "Incorrect password."
        render 'new'  
      else 
        flash.now[:danger] = "Something went wrong. Please try again."
        render 'new'
      end
    elsif !user 
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Incorrect email'
      render 'new'
    else  
      flash.now[:danger] = "Something went wrong, please try again or contact support."
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

This works from trial/error testing but does not look ideal/DRY.

Comment: checkout https://github.com/bootstrap-ruby/rails-bootstrap-forms, you can use it with your failed to save object, and the form will display some nice red like error messages. The error text message will be the one you defined in your model's validations.

Comment: will that work despite there not being a session Active Record model?

Comment: @fanta "defined in your model's validations" -- there is no session model. see this: **#8.7** https://www.railstutorial.org/book/basic_login

Comment: I'm not talking about a Session model. Why do you need to store the errors in the `session` object ?. Rails gives you validations for your models. What I was talking about is to use those validations and display the error messages with rails bootstrap. There's another way you could do what you're trying to accomplish here, it will make your controller look cleaner, and that is to use Form Objects, take a look here https://robots.thoughtbot.com/activemodel-form-objects.

Comment: Bootstrap forms is not the answer because bootstrap is a CSS framework. It will only stylize any flash messages you show, has absolutely nothing to do with ActiveRecord

Comment: form objects seems to be closer to a solution

Comment: @fanta So my `class Session` `session.rb` is not going to be an active record model, it is like a module? and `attr_accessor` allows me to validate the instance variables being passed in the `:session` form before they are run through the official User model validations? `attr_accessor` is like a _temporary_ instance variable?

Comment: @RichardPeck I am confused because my validations are in the User model and I do not know how I am supposed to show them when the form object is :session and there is no Session model.

Comment: @fanta i am really confused about this line of code `@registration.register` what is `register`?

Comment: @TimmyVonHeiss `Registration` is the Form Object that's going to validate(by executing `valid?`) your data. In the example, `Registration` class includes `ActiveModel::Model` to be able to use `validates `, that `validates` validates `company_name ` and all the fields you see there. You could build something like that, that way let's say you define your object @user_authentication = UserAuthentication.new(params).authenticate, and if there are errors, you can use @user_authentication in your template and access the errors wherever you defined them.